# Throw exception in scripted patch

Tags: ravendb

Is there a way to explicitly throw exception in RavenDb Scripted Patch? I could workaround it by calling `null.SomeMethod` and having a NullReferenceException as result but I'd like to throw a specific exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just standard JS:

```
throw "Too big";    // throw a text
throw 500;          // throw a number
```